# php form bootstrap modal after submit modal stay open

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

how to? php form bootstrap modal after submit modal stay open and echo $error
i want after click on submit in form modal, modal stay open 
and i can see the $error from php change

```
<!-- signIn modal -->
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="signInModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading"><h3>התחבר</h3></div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form action="" method="POST" role="form" id="signInForm">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="InputEmail">הכנס אימייל</label>
                                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <label for="InputPassword">הכנס סיסמא</label>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="InputPassword">
                                    </div>

                                    <button  type="submit" id="signInBtn" value="signin" name="submit1" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">כניסה</button>

                                    <span><?= $error; ?></span>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You form action="" needs an URL to submit to

Comment: Try use this JQuery hide() method:$('#signInBtn').submit(function(){
  $('.portfolio-modal').hide();
});

Comment: In the button add a attribute data-dismiss="modal"

Comment: use ajax to submit form prevent.default the action , and get result form ajax and show error using jquery